# SQL Query not ordering results properly

Tags: php, sql

I'm querying my database to return a set of results from highest to lowest. But, it seems as if the query isn't entirely ordering the results that way. My code is as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$stats_table." ORDER BY ppg DESC")or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
$team[$i] = $row['team'];
    $ppg[$i]  = $row['ppg'];

    $i++;
}

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
echo "".$ppg[$i]." <br /><br />";
}
```

When I echo out the ppg column set I get the following:

```
99.7

98.2

97.8

97.4

97.1

96.9

96.8

96.3

96.2

95.5

94.6

94.5

94.3

93.9

93.2

92.8

92.2

91.5

90.8

90.3

106.0

105.9

104.5

103.6

102.6

101.9

101.5

101.3

100.7

100.1
```

It seems that for all of the values less than 100 and over 100 it works. But, how can I make this order work with all values instead of just within those less than and above 100?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: which data type have you assigned to ppg ?

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Awwwww. That sucks. Is it hard to switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `ppg` double, real or anything numeric, not varchar.

Comment: I changed it from varhcar to int. But, now the problem is that I can't have decimal values in there.

Comment: change your datatype to float this may help

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type to numeric like double, real, float. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ORDER BY ABS(ppg) if you don't want to touch your structure

Answer (score 0):

You could let PHP sort it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$stats_table)or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $team[$i] = $row['team'];
    $ppg[$i]  = (int)$row['ppg'];
    $i++;
}
sort($ppg, SORT_NUMERIC);
for($i=0;$i<count($ppg);$i++) {
     echo $ppg[$i]." <br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Yup. I could do it that way too. Is that quicker than using mysql_num_rows?

Comment: Well using count() to count the array $ppg is definitely smarter (and safer) than using the count of mysql_num_rows since the array $ppg could potentially have a different amount of items than mysql_num_rows counted.